# Does initializing a reference to a non-instantiated object cause memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, constructor, reference

This question is similar to the [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770459/c-initializing-reference-with-a-parameter), but here I'm interested in a slightly different issue (memory leak). I have a C# background, so I'm uncertain of C++ behavior in the following scenario.

Consider the classes `A` and `B` defined as below:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int k) : A(k,B(0)) {} // does this cause memory leak?
    A(int k, B& b) : b(b) { this->ind = k; }
    B& b;
    int ind;
};
class B
{
public:
    B(int j) { this->ind = j; }
    int ind;
}
```

If I instantiate class A by:

```
A* a = new A(0);
```

it generates a "default" `b` inside `a`, since the `A` constructor creates a temporary object `B(0)` object to construct `a`.

- Is this a good programming practice in C++? If not, what would be
  recommended for this scenario?
- Would this scenario cause memory leak when `a` is destroyed? Or the reference to `B(0)` is simply in a temporary memory place and won't really matter?

Comment: Have you run this code through compiler? Try it.

Comment: Your code can't compile so no, there will be no leak

Comment: If you fix your code to compile, it does not leak.  It has a dangling reference.

Comment: [ProTip] You can only have a memory leak if you use `new` (lets pretend `malloc` doesn't exist).  If there is no new, there is no leak.

Comment: you mean it won't compile just because of the order of the definition of the classes?